# FTP login via vsftpd

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ftp

There seems to be quite a lot of posts about FTP login via vsftpd but none worked for me. I'm aware that FTP is not really secure but I have an uploader page which uses FTP to upload content to server. This content is not executed anywhere but just stored and I use clamAV for virus scanning these content, just in case.

Here's the commands that I tried.

`sudo useradd -d /home/publicftp -m publicftp`

Then vsftpd config

```
local_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

All other properties are commented out. My problem is that from filezilla if I use port 21 (FTP) **connection is timed out. However, if I use port 22 (SFTP), then publicftp can connect and access all folders** - meaning he's not jailed.

Comment: port 22 is (almost certainly) using the SSH server and your vsftp config will have no impact on that.  Since the connection timed out perhaps there's a firewall in the way or vsftp is not really listening.  do you get anything from `netstat -an | grep 21` or `ps ax | grep ftp`?

Comment: vsftp is actually listening on port 21. I did not take a backup of vsftpd conf, so purged the package and reinstalled. FTP works with this fresh config. But if I modify it to aforementioned block of code, then bingo! it's gone. Trying to debug which particular property is causing the error.

Comment: As for SFTP, found a solution which invloves /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: Change your parameters one at a time.

Comment: i'm going to guess that it's this line: `secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty` either it doesn't exist or the permissions are not right...?

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble. While I was working with vsftpd on the server, one of my colleague was actually playing around with inbound ports for the same instance. That's the reason for the trouble. However, empty directory was also the issue. I changed it to a location I wanted. And it worked fine.